# Remove-ADComputer with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, active-directory

Is it possible to execute Active Directory related commands with PowerShell Lambda function?

The goal is to remove a windows host from AD with *Remove-ADComputer* command

I tried to import the ActiveDirectory module but it isn't recognised.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
```

Additional as a required module I added :

```
#Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWS.Tools.DirectoryService';ModuleVersion='4.1.0.0'}
```

But without luck.

As base modules I set:

```
#Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWS.Tools.Common';ModuleVersion='4.1.0.0'}
#Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWS.Tools.SimpleSystemsManagement';ModuleVersion='4.1.0.0'}
```

Comment: Is this for a "classic" AD deployment or an AWS Directory Service deployment? If classic, do you have VPN set up between your VPC in AWS and the on-prem network hosting your domain controllers?

Comment: yes, this is classic AD development. For now, I execute all Remove-ADComputer commands on dedicated windows ec2 instances. But, I'd  like to move this functionality from ec2 to lambda.

Comment: I think you'll need to connect to a domain-joined windows box with the RSAT module installed if you want to use `Remove-ADComputer` - so you're AWS Lambda would just be doing `Invoke-Command { Remove-ADComputer } -CN ec2domainMemberFqdn`. You might want to wrap the AD commands on the ec2 instance in [a JEA endpoint configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview).

Comment: This is how my solution looks like now. But, I am trying to remove ec2 instances from the flow and put lambda function over there. It seems that lambda with PowerShell scripts is not going to work. So, I am going to try with Python and any ldap / ad module.

Answer (score 0):

Unfotunately, as of the date of this posting it is not possible to run "Remove-ADComputer" PowerShell cmdlet inside an AWS Lambda PowerShell function.

AWS.Tools.DirectoryServices module do not offer a command for this purpose.

Also, AWS CLI for AWS Managed Directories does not offer a command to remove a computer object. You can add a new one, but cannot remove nan existing server. :)
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ds/index.html#cli-aws-ds

Therefore, you will have to run your command on an EC2 instance with RSAT tools installed - preferably joined to the directory you are working in.

AWS Managed Directory Services offers a management server that can be provisioned and used for this purpose.

PS: As of the date of the posting it is the same for Azure functions. So, no serverless options for removing a server from an active directory domain.